# Remap Caps Lock to Esc and Ctrl

Tags: vi, remapping

After watching some videos about `tmux` and `vim` collaboration I wanna remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  on my ubuntu.

Remapping <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  to <kbd>Esc</kbd>  is easy I used `gnome-tweak-tool`, but now I wanna change <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  behavior to work as <kbd>Esc</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in some situations.

When I use only <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  it works like <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
When I use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  with some other key it works like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +something.
How do I do that?

Comment: I really doubt that it can be done without rewriting the X keyboard interface. I personally have remapped Caps to Esc, and Esc to Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using xmodmap. Please find the documentation here or ArchWiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Be careful though, sometimes a few portion is only Arch related.

Alternatively you can use two different shortcuts CAPS+ and CTRL+ to execute same commands in Menu > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

[Gnome Tweak Tools Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPTPF.png)
In the new Gnome Tweak Tools, there is an option to swap the Esc key and the Caps lock key. It's located under the Keyboard and Mouse tab, and the Additional Layouts Button. This is on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use this config (cf. the keyd Quickstart):

```
[ids]

*

[main]

# Maps capslock to escape when pressed and control when held.
capslock = overload(control, esc)
```