# Remap a key combination to another combination, e.g. AltGr+C -> Ctrl+C, under Wayland

Tags: keyboard-layout, wayland, shortcut-keys, remapping

### **TL;DR**

Under Wayland, can I somehow bind `AltGr + C` to `Ctrl + C`?

### **Details**

I basically want to ask [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/834650/13884), **but for GNOME on Wayland**. This means that answers involving [AutoKey](https://askubuntu.com/a/106834/13884) and [xbindkeys](https://askubuntu.com/a/839531/13884) wont work, as neither works under Wayland.

**Background**

I would like to remap some keys to ultimately make better use of `CapsLock`.

My plan is to map `CapsLock` to `AltGr`, and then follow [this](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-configure-caps-lock-as-altgr-and-arrows-like-in-vim/) to obtain vim-like keybindings. On Wayland, this remapping can be done through XKB files (see the link).

However, I would also like to use `CapsLock` for copy/pasting. Currently, I have it mapped to `Ctrl` (using XKB files). This makes `CapsLock + C` work smoothly throughout the system, and I would like to preserve this.

So: With `CapsLock` mapped to `AltGr`, I would like `Capslock (= AltGr) + C` to act as `Ctrl + C`.

**My question**

Under Wayland, can I somehow bind `AltGr + C` to `Ctrl + C`?

(Without just rebinding `AltGr` to `Ctrl`, as that would defeat the purpose)

**An alternative example with Q**

In the XKB file for latin `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/latin`, the following behavior is defined for my `Q` key:

```
key <AD01>  { [ q, Q, at, Greek_OMEGA ] };
```

This states that the key has four possible outputs:

1. Pressed alone, it produces `q`.
2. Pressed with `Shift`, it produces `Q`.
3. Pressed with `AltGr`, it produces `@`.
4. Pressed with `AltGr + Shift`, it produces `Ω`.

Essentially what I would like to achieve is that when `Q` is pressed with `AltGr`, it does not produce `@` but `Ctrl + Q`.

Comment: The "best answer" part in https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-configure-caps-lock-as-altgr-and-arrows-like-in-vim/, changing xkb, will also work on Wayland.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you, yes, that I am aware of and use already. I have now added detail to clarify the question. If XKB can be used for the purpose described, that would be excellent news! Alas, I have no clue what syntax to experiment with.

Comment: OK, the specificity is clearer now. That specific change will require some "fake typing" solution. There is `ydotool` and possibly some other tools. Binding then can be done from within your window manager instead of `xmodmap`. No experience myself, so that is why I cannot develop this in an answer for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several tools exist that may do this, like [KMonad](https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad), [Interception Tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools), and [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd).

I've had complete success with `keyd` under Wayland, so I describe what I did with that. I suggest reading the short [the README](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for inspiration. The deamon can do a lot more than what's used here.

The present solution does what I want, but circumvents using the `AltGr` detour. It treats `CapsLock` as `Control` everywhere, except in `h ,j ,k , l`, which it changes to arrow keys.

**1. INSTALLATION**

I build `keyd` from source, as that was easy. The next lines first install dependencies (including C compiler), downloads the source, builds and installs it, and enables it as service, and starts it and runs it at startup.

When done, it'll tell you where it installed what so you can delete it for uninstall. You can delete the source code after installation.

```
sudo apt install cmake libudev-dev
git clone https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd
cd keyd
make && sudo make install
sudo systemctl enable keyd && sudo systemctl start keyd
```

**2. FIND THE NAME OF THE KEYBOARD YOU WANT TO REMAP**

*You can skip this step and remap the default keyboard, see below on `default.conf`*

You should find the name of your keyboard, so we can make a remapping just for that. Run

```
sudo keyd -m
```

and press some keys. It'll show the name of the keyboard and the keys pressed. Note down the name. Mine was `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`.

*Tip: `keyd -m` is useful find the name of keys by pressing them. `keyd -l` lists the key names you can map to.*

**3. MAKE A CONFIGURATION FILE**

Wherever, make a configuration file called whatever. We'll move it later. Let's say you use `~/my_keyboard.conf`.

In it, put the following. The #'ed are comments that explains the behavior defined:

```
[ids]

# The keyboards remapped. * for all, else explicit IDs.
*

[main]
### MAIN LAYER
    
# Make capslock activate the second layer:

capslock = layer(movement_layer)

### SECOND LAYER (called "movement_layer")

# Define the new layer, which while active
# by default treats every key as if Control was pressed,
# (":C" means the layer should inherit the Control layer),
# and overrides this default for only h, j, k and l, which
# are mapped to directions.

[movement_layer:C]

h = left
j = down
k = up
l = right

# In sum, in the main default layer, everything is standard, except
# when CapsLock is pressed, then the second layer is activated.
# When the second layer is activate, everything but h, j, k, l
# acts as if Control is held---e.g., c copies and v pastes,
# which we want, as we are holding down CapsLock.)
```

**4. COPY AND RENAME THE CONFIGURATION FILE AND RESTART KEYD**

Next, we copy the configuration to the right location and name it properly, namely according to the keyboard we want to remap.

```
sudo cp ~/my_keyboard.conf /etc/keyd/AT\ Translated\ Set\ 2\ keyboard.conf
```

### Note on `default.conf` and keyboard IDs

*You can also copy your config file to `/etc/keyd/default.conf` to make it apply to all keyboards. But if you mess up and remap your Enter key, you cannot plugin another keyboard to undo the changes...
You can however replace the `*` (for "all") under `[ids]` with ids of keyboards for which to apply the remapping. From `keyd -m`, note down the `<vendor id>:<product id>` of your keyboard. Mine is `0002:000a`. Replace `*` with your `0002:000a`.*

We then restart `keyd` so it loads the new configuration:

```
sudo systemctl restart keyd
```

You're now up and running :)

**5. CREATE AN ALIAS TO COPY CONFIG AND RESTART KEYD**

I ended up playing a lot with the config files. I edited them in a subdirectory of my home folder, then copied them over and restarted keyd.

To make this less of a hassle, in `~/.bash_aliases`, I added

```
alias rekeyd='sudo cp ~/my_keyboard.conf /etc/keyd/AT\ Translated\ Set\ 2\ keyboard.conf && sudo systemctl restart keyd'
```

Comment: This works very well.  Sometimes you don't know the name of a key, and there are two ways to find out- 1) List all available keys with `keyd list-keys | sort`, and 2) Display keys as they are pressed with `sudo keyd monitor`.

Comment: My keyboard is named `Logitech N305/B505` how do I create a conf file for it?

Comment: @bky, I think you have to use `default.conf`, due to the forward slash in the name. I'm updating the answer now.

Comment: I found out that I can use `Logitech N305.conf` which seems to work. And, btw, thank you for your awesome answer.