# How can I remap Home to F5 and End to F11?

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I've edited the /use/share/X11/xkd/pc file to remap some keys, but I can't quite figure out how to assign Home and End to F5 and F11.

Any assists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use this config:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

home = f5
end = f11
```

(I hope I got you correctly: With this, pressing `home` will produce `f5`, and so will pressing `f5`. If you want `f5` to produce `home`, just flip the  `=`)