# How to remap Caps Lock to letter key, such as "a"

Tags: keyboard, remapping

There are many questions on here about remapping `Caps Lock` to another special key, such as `Ctrl` or `Esc`. However, I want to map `Caps Lock` to the `A` key. (My keyboard's physical `A` key broke, so when I don't have an external keyboard plugged in, to type `A` I have to use an on-screen keyboard which is not as convenient, and sometimes very difficult like on certain login screens.)

As mentioned, many existing answers talk about settings that already exist for disabling `Caps Lock`, or swapping `Caps Lock` and `Esc`, but none of those preexisting settings are what I need.

I have tried using `xmodmap` to no avail, and additionally the `setxkbmap` options `ctrl:nocaps` and `caps:none` do not even disable `Caps Lock` for me, but that might be a separate issue. Just included in case it's a helpful clue, but it is not the primary problem.

Comment: They call it the input mapper now, but it is something that might be able to help you:  https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/remap-keyboard-gamepad-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use this config:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

capslock = a
```