# How do you disable all Super key shortcuts in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to use the Super key as a modifier for keyboard *and* mouse shortcuts in other applications. However, Gnome seems to have dozens of keybinds that are tied to that key and that appears to affect its usability as a modifier in some apps (notably, I can't use it as a modifier in IntelliJ). I've removed the ones I could find in Settings, but there are a couple I can't find defined anywhere:

- Super to open application launcher
- Super+drag to move windows around

Is there a way to disable these in Gnome so that I can use it as a modifier?

Comment: @Quasímodo I can do that, but I'm not sure how to do it in such a way that Gnome will respect it. I asked a question about that a week ago, Gnome seems to not respect remapping keys: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439814/how-do-you-swap-the-alt-win-keys-and-map-win-key-to-meta-in-gnome.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one way to disable all <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combination. They are defined in different places. "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts" is the first place to look for several of them and disable/change them. Others are in different places.

The command `gsettings list-recursively | grep '<Super>'` will give you a good idea on the different places where <kbd>Super</kbd> is assigned. You can then either use the `gsettings` command or the graphical tool `dconf-editor` (not installed by default) to change the settings.

For the two examples you provided:

**Super to open application launcher**

Disable with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

**Super+drag to move windows around**

In Gnome Tweaks, Window Tab, disable the "Window Action Key" or set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Alternatively, use `gsettings` to disable the key or set it to another modifier key (e.g. `<alt>` or `<Control>`).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier 'disabled'
```