# Customizing shortcuts and keyboard layering (not with regular settings, they're too limited)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'm trying to create these shortcuts:

- Remap `ctrl+c,v,x` to `ctrl+j,k,q` because I'm using Dvorak layout.
- `alt+i,j,k,l` to arrow keys. And it must work with the other modifiers, like `shift+alt+l` -> `shift+right`.

I used to have this on Windows, configured with a really great app AutoHotKey. But on Linux, surprisingly, there are no such straightforward options.

What doesn't work:

- Regular settings. I can't even change copy-paste there, and even if I could, there would be another problem (happened on MacOS): Basically, I need to silence `ctrl+j` and emit `ctrl+c`, not just do copy when I press `ctrl+j`. This is because other apps don't expect such weird combinations and can have some other functionality assigned to it that would conflict.
- Third party apps:

  - AutoKey: It doesn't silence the shortcuts used to execute scripts. So if I write a script to emit `Up` when I press `alt+i`, the system will see `alt+i+Up`.
  - Ktrl: It was working (with two very annoying bugs), but I just got a new laptop and installed newer version of Ubuntu, and it doesn't work here now. Plus I really don't want to deal with those bugs anymore.
  - I have looked into other apps and couldn't find anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below. It makes left Control activate a layer, `customcontrol`, while held, where every thing you press is be default modified by Control (the `:C`), except for the keys remapped in the layer---in this case `x`, `c` and `v` which are remapped to `Control + q` etc. Same-same for left Alt.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

leftcontrol = layer(customcontrol)
leftalt = layer(customalt)

[customcontrol:C]

x = C-q
c = C-j
v = C-k

[customalt:A]
i = up
k = down 
j = left
l = right
```

Comment: I ended up using kmonad, actually. I should've posted the update here but forgot... This one looks interesting too, I'll check it out