# Change right Shift key to work as Enter

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My keyboard has a small Enter key and the right Shift which is bigger and I do not really use it. Would it be possible to remap the right Shift key to work as the Enter key, as well?

I tried this but it did not work. 62 is my right SHift (used xev for that) but maybe Enter is not the right command, or maybe it is wrong altogether.

xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Enter"

Comment: You used Xev to find the keycode, now with the same tool you just need to find the keysym by pressing Enter, to find the answer: `Return`. Right under your nose :P

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Return instead Enter works like a charm. Please consider making an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

rightshift = enter
```