# How to change keyboard layout by switching 1234567890 with !@#$%^&*() with Shift or Num Lock keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

What I would like to do is, instead of pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to see `!` or `@` respectively, have by default `! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )` instead of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`, and maybe if I have my <kbd>NumLock</kbd> off it could be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`. But if <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is off I would have `! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )` in the first row, and could have access to the numbers if I use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Can someone get me to the right track?

```
// Begin: Insert 42lx by cosvaldo@42lx.com
// This file is called 42lx and must be placed into the following linux folder:
// /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    name[Group1]= "US/ASCII";
    key <AE01> { [   1,          exclam,           exclamdown,      onesuperior ] };
    key <AE02> { [   2,              at,          twosuperior, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AE03> { [   3,      numbersign,        threesuperior,      dead_macron ] };
    key <AE04> { [   4,          dollar,             currency,         sterling ] };
    key <AE05> { [   5,         percent,             EuroSign,     dead_cedilla ] };
    key <AE06> { [   6, dead_circumflex,           onequarter,      asciicircum ] };
    key <AE07> { [   7,       ampersand,              onehalf,        dead_horn ] };
    key <AE08> { [   8,        asterisk,        threequarters,      dead_ogonek ] };
    key <AE09> { [   9,       parenleft,  leftsinglequotemark,       dead_breve ] };
    key <AE10> { [   0,      parenright, rightsinglequotemark,   dead_abovering ] };
    modifier_map Shift   { Num_Lock };
    //modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
    //modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
    // key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock  ]   };
};
// End: Insert 42lx by cosvaldo@42lx.com
```

I also will insert this code:

```xml
// /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
// It will be inserted at line ... this code in evdev.xml:
    <!-- Begin: Insert 42lx by cosvaldo@42lx.com -->
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>42lx</name>
        <shortDescription>42lx.com</shortDescription>
        <description>42lx English (US): switch between numbers and signs at the
        first line, below function keys with Num Lock, Left and Right
        Shift.</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
          <iso639Id>por</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList/>
    </layout>
    <!-- End: Insert 42lx by cosvaldo@42lx.com -->
```

I already saw this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/706210#706210), but something is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below (plus lines for `4`-`0`, obviously). The config uses `f12` to toggle between two layers, one where `1`-`3` act normally (the default `main` layer), one where they act as if shift is pressed (I called it `f12layer`). You can use something else than `f12`. Run `keyd -m`, press the key you want to use as a toggle, note the name, change and reload the config.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

f12 = toggle(f12layer)

[f12layer]

f12 = toggle(f12layer)
1 = S-1
2 = S-2
3 = S-3
```