# reassigning 'Tab' key to 'insert' key

Tags: keyboard, remapping

**Background**: I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I am new to Linux. I do not have a programming or computer science background.

**Problem**: I am trying to reassign the function of 'Tab' to the 'Insert' key as the main 'Tab' key is broken.

**Solutions tried:**
I went through the following steps:

1. Found out the keycode for the 'Insert' key using *xmodmap -pke* command.
2. Used the command *xmodmap -e "keycode 118 = Tab"* command to assign the key to tab.
3. running *xmodmap -pke* command again shows that keycode 118 has been assigned to 'Tab' key.
4. However, when pressed, 'Insert' key does not act as 'tab' key.

I am at a loss. What went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check numlock key is on (or off). or make Settings, Keyboard, custom shortcut to do a 'xdotool key ins  ' for the tab key

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

# Make Insert key execute Tab function:
insert = tab
```