# Remap Ctrl+, and Ctrl+. to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

Tags: remapping

Can I somehow define a remapping where `F12` toggles a new layer in which `Ctrl+,` acts as `Ctrl+c` and `Ctrl+.` acts as `Ctrl+v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use this config:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

f12 = toggle(f12layer)

[f12layer]

f12 = toggle(f12layer)
leftcontrol = layer(commadotlayer)

[commadotlayer:C]
comma = C-c
dot = C-v
```